# How do I write an sql query to display items from 2 tables based on a selection of a criteria which is from a different table

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

How do I write an sql query to display items from 2 tables based on a selection of a criteria which is from a different table.

Tables I have:

1. **Customer** table has columns CustomerID, Name, Address, Tel
2. **CustomerOrder** table has columns CustomerID, OrderID, Date, TotalAmount, Status
3. **OrderItem** table has columns OrderID, ProductCode, UnitPrice, Qty, TotalPrice

So when a CustomerID is selected, I want the orders to be displayed joining these 3 tables. so as below it should display all the orders that the customer has ever placed. 
I tried using the query:

```
Select CustomerOrder.*, OrderItem.*
From CustomerOrder
INNER JOIN OrderItem Where Customer.CustomerID = $CustomerID
```

But it's not working. Need help in the query and also in displaying the data properly using php.

Can anyone help?

E.g.

```
CustomerID:__________

OrderID:__1____ Date:______ TotalAmount:______ Status:_____
ProductCode:__ UnitPrice:___ Qty:_____TotalPrice:__________
ProductCode:___ UnitPrice:______ Qty:_____ TotalPrice:_________

OrderID:___2___ Date:______ TotalAmount:______ Status:_____
ProductCode:__ UnitPrice:___ Qty:_____TotalPrice:__________
ProductCode:___ UnitPrice:______ Qty:_____ TotalPrice:_________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't need to display Customer information at this step, then you query can be :

```
SELECT co.OrderID
,co.Date
,co.TotalAmount
,co.Status
,ci.ProductCode
,ci.UnitPrice
,ci.Qty
,ci.TotalPrice
FROM CustomerOrder AS co
INNER JOIN OrderItem AS ci ON (ci.orderID = co.OrderID)
WHERE co.CustomerID = $customer
ORDER BY co.OrderID, ci.ProductCode
```

As you'd like to no repeat order information in your output, your PHP code should be soemthing like this:

```
$current_order_id = false;
foreach ($data as $row) {
   if ($current_order_id!==$row['OrderID']) {
        $current_order_id = $row['OrderID'];
        echo "OrderID: ".$row['OrderID']." , Date: ".$row['Date']." , TotalAmount: ".$row['TotalAmount']." , Status: ".$row['Status']." <br>";
   }
   echo "ProductCode: ".$row['ProductCode']." , UnitPrice: ".$row['UnitPrice']." , Qty: ".$row['Qty']." , TotalPrice: ".$row['TotalPrice']." <br>";
}
```

Anothere way of doing the same is to first get all the Orders information from `CustomerOrder` only.
And then loop on the result and get items infotmation `OrderItem` for each order.

Comment: error is Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\listorderbycustomertest.php on line 74

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\listorderbycustomertest.php on line 74

Comment: is this how it should be: $query = "SELECT co.OrderID
,co.Date.....; $result = mysql_query($query);   
$current_order_id = false;.... ????

Comment: i changed this $result = mysql_query($query);  to $data = mysql_query($query); now the error is Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\listorderbycustomertest.php on line 74

Comment: This is problem of using mysql php functions. mysql_query() returns a resource pointing on a recordset, not an array of data. You should replace `foreach ($data as $row)` with `while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($data))`.

Comment: error again. now: 
Notice: Undefined index: OrderID in C:\xampp\htdocs.. this error repeats for every field that we are displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: 
`SELECT co.OrderID,date,TotalAmount,ProductCode, UnitPrice,Qty,TotalPrice,Status  FROM CustomerOrder AS co 
INNER JOIN OrderItem AS oi ON oi.orderID = co.OrderID
INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON c.CustomerID = co.CustomerID
WHERE c.CustomerID = $customer`

Comment: @Skrol29 The question was not properly formated so i thought the Status was a table. Fixed it.

Comment: can use a different join : left join or right join as one CustomerOrder can have a few orderitem.